# JAVA | Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java

¿Por qué devuelve el siguiente error?

**Error: Could not find or load main class Main**

*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
Command execution failed.*

**Main:**

```
package Calculando2;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 10;
        int n2 = 2;
       Operacion op1 = new Operacion();
       op1.sumar(n1,n2);
       op1.restar(n1,n2);
       op1.multiplicar(n1,n2);
       op1.dividir(n1,n2);
       op1.mostrar();
    } 
}
```

**Operacion:**

```
package Calculando2;
public class Operacion {
    //Atributos
    int suma;
    int resta;
    int multiplicacion;
    int division;

    //Métodos
    public void sumar(int numero1, int numero2){
        suma = numero1 + numero2;
    }
    public void restar(int numero1, int numero2){
        resta = numero1 - numero2;
    }
    public void multiplicar(int numero1, int numero2){
        multiplicacion = numero1 * numero2;
    }
    public void dividir(int numero1, int numero2){
        division = numero1 / numero2;
    }
    public void mostrar(){
    System.out.println("suma = " + suma);
    System.out.println("resta = " + resta);
    System.out.println("multiplicacion = " + multiplicacion);
    System.out.println("division = " + division);

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás compilando desde la línea de comandos?

Comment: Revisa la definicion que tenes de tu CLASSPATH.

Comment: ¿El error lo obtienes al ejecutar el código desde el IDE o al ejecutar el .jar desde la consola?

Comment: El error lo obtengo al ejecutar el código desde el IDE netbeans. Un saludo.

Comment: Yo ese error lo he resuelto dándole Clean and Build al proyecto. Supongo que falla porque le falta cargar algunas librerías o dependencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola buenas tu código esta bien. Que programa usas para programar me he llevado tu codigo a netbeans y funciona todo aqui tienes la imagen. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posibles solucines : https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-solucionar-el-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-en-java.aspx

Resumen :

1.- El paquete no está disponible en el Classpath
Si tienes dudas sobre dónde está ubicado el Classpath puedes mostrar por pantalla la ruta usando:
 `System.getproperty("java.classpath")`

2.- Faltan permisos suficientes
Algún problema de permisos puede estar impidiendo que se puedan cargar las clases de un archivo .jar y que se produzca la excepción NoClassDefFoundError.

Debes asegurarte de que el usuario actual tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a los archivos. Esto es especialmente importante en el caso de que algún paquete sea compartido y por lo tanto pueda tener unos permisos establecidos por otro usuario, sin haber creado permisos que aseguren el acceso por parte de todos los usuarios.

3.- Falta alguna dependencia de terceros

Alguna dependencia del programa, por ejemplo una biblioteca nativa, no está disponible en el equipo actual, pero sí lo estaba en el equipo en el que se compiló.

Determina cuál es mirando el log de errores e instálala en el equipo actual.

4.- Falta de visibilidad entre niveles de la jerarquía del ClassLoader

En J2EE, como hemos explicado antes, la falta de visibilidad de la clase entre los diferentes niveles de la jerarquía en el proceso de carga puede provocar esta situación.

5.- Un script de inicialización sobrescribe a ClassPath

Una posibilidad menos frecuente, pero que puede darse es cuando un script de inicialización del programa está sobrescribiendo la variable de entorno Classpath, lo cual hace que el resto del programa no pueda encontrar los archivos .jar apropiados.

Prueba con lo comentado en el punto 1 para ver si se está usando la ruta correcta.

6.- Errores en un bloque de inicialización estática

Si el programa utiliza un bloque de inicialización estática (por ejemplo, es típico con clases de tipo Singleton, que no permiten más que una instancia), es posible que no se encuentre alguna referencia que se use desde ahí.

7.- JDK desconfigurado o mal instalado

Si alguna de las variables ClassPath, JAVA_HOME o PATH está mal establecida debido a algún problema de la instalación de Java, vamos a obtener errores de tipo NoClassDefFoundError, por supuesto. En este caso habría que reinstalar el runtime de Java para solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

No he encontrado ningún error.
Asegurate de que tus dos clases estén dentro de una carpeta que se llame `Calculando2`.
Ya que cuando usas un paquete las clases se deben encontrar en una carpeta que tenga el mismo nombre del paquete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Están en la misma carpeta. No se qué sucede la verdad. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: ¿Haz intentado copiar el código en nuevos archivos dentro de otro paquete? Me ha pasado exactamente lo mismo un par de veces ._.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Otra cosa que puede ser hacer lo siguiente si usas Eclipse y Maven :
Clic Derecho en el proyecto:
Run AS **>** Maven Install

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y después

Clic Derecho en el proyecto:
Run AS **>** Java Applicatuion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Hola te dejo como lo solucioné luego de tres meses de sufrimiento.

En el directorio donde tenía el proyecto había una carpeta en la ruta con tilde en el nombre "Programación".

Solo tuve que quitarle la tilde y listo, se me solucionó.

Espero te sirva o a alguien que estuvo buscando tanto tiempo como yo.

Saludos!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Solo queria dejarlo para que alguein tenga otra opción si no le resultan las otras soluciones, como me psso a mí que estuve 3 meses estancado. Gracias y revisaré lo que me aconsejas. Saludos