# Error con el path de libraries

Tags: java

como están? Tengo un problema en la ejecución del proyecto java en spring tools 4.

> ```
> Error : Could not find or load main class com.ProductsAPI.app.ProductsApiApplication
> Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ProductsAPI.app.ProductsApiApplication.
> ```

Ya he intentado eliminar la librería JRE y volverla a agregar pero no me dió resultado. Al parecer tengo que poner el .jar en la carpeta donde se ubica el proyecto pero no sé como hacerlo. Que archivo debería ser y en que carpeta en específico debo ponerlo

Comment: No encuentra la clase ProductsApiApplication. Deberás añadir referencias/dependencias del JAR (java application library, no Java Runtime Enviroment) que contiene esa clase. La manera de hacerlo depende del tipo de proyecto de Java que tengas, que puede ser Ant, Maven o Gradle.

Comment: No creo que el problema tenga que ver con los jar externos. Lo que no está encontrando es una clase tuya, no una clase de un paquete externo (por el nombre supongo que `ProductsApiApplication` la creaste tú). Desafortunadamente es necesario más detalles para poder ayudarte. Cosas como la estructura de tu proyecto, cómo lo estás ejecutando, IDE, etc. Checa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324774/java-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-main) a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez podría ser, sí. Pero también podría ser un JAR externo proporcionado por un amigo suyo que no sigue los estándares. Lo que está claro es que falta más detalles sobre su proyecto.

Comment: Es maven y puse las dependencias cuando cree el proyecto. Fueron Spring Boot DevTools, MySQL Driver, Spring Data JPA, Spring Security, Spring Web, Spring Data Jdbc, Tomcat, Lombock, y creo que 2 más que ahora no recuerdo. La ProductsApiApplication la creó el proyecto cuando lo inicie. Estoy usando Spring Tools 4 con java 8.

Comment: En la sugerencia me dice que Configure el build path pero ya lo hice y no funciona