# no entiendo este error .JOptionPane

Tags: java

No entiendo el error espero no saltarme una regla soy nuevo aquí, y también nuevo en java, esto es un programa que me pida datos en una ventanita jiji.

```
package flotantes;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class flotantes {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadena;
        int entero;
        char letra;
        double decimal;
        
        cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una cadena: ");
        entero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un entero: "));
        letra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una letra: ").charAt(0);
        decimal = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un decimal: "));
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cadena);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, entero);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letra);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, decimal);
    }

}
```

//codigo de jaider no me lo robes que me enojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
cabe recalcar que el programa me genera error al ejecutarlo nada mas, en las líneas de código no me dice que algo esta mal

Comment: lo mas seguro es que no tienes instalada la libreria de JOptionPane

Comment: sabes como instalarla bro ? puede ser eso porque llevo como 4 horas intentando volviendo a escribir el código y todo pero no. No sigo hasta que lo soluciones jaja

Comment: intenta con estas soluciones y si ya de plano no te funciona, desinstala el JDK de java y vuelvelo a instalar (la version mas actualizada) https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-solucionar-el-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-en-java.aspx

Comment: gracias compa por ayudarme

Comment: si te funciono?

Comment: si muchas gracias descargue la ultima versión del JDK

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [JAVA | Could not find or load main class Main](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324774/java-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-main)

Comment: por cierto algo me dice que tienes un `import com.mycompany.joptionpane.JOptionPane` en vez del import de swing